# creation of registration page using facebook

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, yii

I want to create a registration form, with an option to either the register using form on my web page or using facebook account. How can I do this ? Is their any tutorial available to create such kind of registration form.?

Comment: Accept some answers from your questions if they helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer this tutorial , this what you asked : http://www.9lessons.info/2011/01/user-signup-using-facebook-data.html